# Query Constraint Clauses With Schema and Table (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to query the constraint clauses along with schema and table in postgres. I've gotten as far as identifying `information_schema.check_constraints` as a useful table. The problem is that doing

```
select *
from information_schema.check_constraints
```

Results in `constraint_catalog`, `constraint_schema`, `constraint_name`, `check_clause`. The `check_clause` is what I want and this table also gives me the `constraint_schema`. However, it does not give the table that this constraint is defined on. In my current database, I have constraints with the same name defined on different tables within the same schema (which is in it of itself perhaps poor design but what I need to deal with). Is it possible to get the table name here as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  conname,
  connamespace::regnamespace as schemaname,
  conrelid::regclass as tablename,
  consrc as checkclause,
  pg_get_constraintdef(oid) as definition
from
  pg_constraint
where
  contype = 'c'
  and conrelid <> 0; -- to get only table constraints
```

[About `pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html)

[About Object Identifier Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html)